# Disprove the statement: If a function is twice differentiable at a local maximum point, then its second derivative is negative at that point

Tags: analysis, functions

I have to develop a counter example that disproves this statement but I am not to sure on how to go about this. Is it something simple that I am forgetting about?

If a function is twice differentiable at a local maximum point, then its second derivative is negative at that point

Comment: Surely by "local maximum" you mean "strict local maximum", no? (otherwise just take a constant function)

Answer (score 16):

COUNTEREXAMPLE:

$f(x)=-x^4$.  At $x=0$, we have $f''(0)=0$.

Comment: I'm curious if there is a strictly positive solution

Comment: @IceArdor $f(x) = 1/(1+x^4).$

Comment: @zhw I was referring to the $f''(x) > 0$ http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5E2%281%2F%281%2Bx%5E4%29%29%2Fdx%5E2+and+1%2F%281%2Bx%5E4%29&x=0&y=0

Comment: OK, but when you write "strictly positive solution" that usually means a solution that is stricly positive. The answer to your question is no. If $f$ has a local max at $x_0,$ then $f'(x_0) = 0.$ So if we have $f''(x_0 )> 0,$ then there is $h> 0$ such that $f'> 0$ on $(x_0,x_0 + h)$ and $f'< 0$ on $(x_0- h, x_0)$ That implies a strict local min, contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Easier counterexample: $$f(x) = 0$$

Comment: But I would think a local maximum means strict local maximum.

Comment: @6005: Hm, I guess I wouldn't...

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample for shigiggles

$f(x) = ln(x)$

Local maxima at $x \to \inf$

Second derivative is $f''(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2}$

$\lim_{x \to \inf} f''(x) = 0$

Comment: Little unclear on what you are trying to say

Comment: Local maximum requires a limit. The second derivative is -1/x², which equals 0 at the local maximum. But the definition of differentiable function is that the left and right limits of the derivative are equal. This means that you have to take a limit approaching infinity from the left and the _right_.

Comment: There's hardly anything local about infinity...

Comment: Since $ln(0)$ isn't defined in reals, I'd assume it's not a minimum either (or differentiable at that point)